# Is there a css minifier that calculates variables from :root {} (possibly from a different file)?

Tags: css, css-variables

I am looking for a CSS minifier, or perhaps just CSS calculator, that will give me CSS with exact values of properties, instead of retaining `var(--root-value)`. Furthermore, if possible, the `:root{}` setting would be in a different file.

So I made this web application template, which I am using for a few different sites. I have several CSS files, the first of them just having `:root{}` setters of values in it, and the rest use

```
selector {
  property: var(--root-value);
}
```

format.

I am using VS Code and it's extension `minify` from `HookyQR`, which in turn uses `clean-css` from `Jakub Pawlowicz` to minify CSS.

I've been searching Google for a better minifier and even just a calculator I could use before minifying with `minify` to calculate those values, but to no avail.

Please advise.

initial-setting.css

```
:root {
    /* COLORS */
    --bg-color: #fff;
    --main-color: #913b86;
    --compl-color: #3b9146;
    --text-color: #666;

    /* DIMENSIONS */
    --navbar-height: 4em;

    /* SHOW/HIDE */
    --show-sidebar: block; /* block for true, none for false */
}
```

style.css

```
.header-navigation>ul>li {
    height: var(--navbar-height);
    line-height: var(--navbar-height);
}

.header .mobi-toggler:hover {
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--main-color) url(../img/icons/toggler.png) no-repeat 6px -28px;
    border-color: var(--main-color);
}
```

Now after calculate I would like to get

style.c.css

```
.header-navigation>ul>li {
    height: 4em;
    line-height: 4em;
}

.header .mobi-toggler:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #913b86 url(../img/icons/toggler.png) no-repeat 6px -28px;
    border-color: #913b86;
}
```

And then minified something like

style.c.min.css

```
.header-navigation>ul>li{height:4em;line-height:4em;}.header .mobi-toggler:hover{color:#fff;background:#913b86 url(../img/icons/toggler.png) no-repeat 6px -28px;border-color:#913b86}
```

or the same thing directly in `style.min.css`.

Comment: a minifier that would do this would be a very BAD one that you need to avoid. Custom properties can be changed later using other CSS or JS

Comment: Questions asking for resource, library, or software recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need a CSS compiler.

I will suggest [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.org) since it has flexible syntax ( you can even write in the same way writing CSS ), but you have access to a thing called **variables** which is the exact thing you're looking for.

You can set'em up just by Stylus or [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) ( based on your choice ) and compile variables to calculate at the compile time, you will get the same result as you want to.

example:

```
$bg-color = #fff;
$main-color = #913b86;
$compl-color = #3b9146;

div {
  color: $main-color;
}
```

Comment: "Get styling with Stylus: 
Installing Stylus is very easy once you have Node.js. So get the binaries for your platform and make sure that they also include npm, Node’s package manager." (from stylus-lang.com). Our company uses PHP servers on Linux environment. Is this still the answer for me?

Comment: @s3c Stylus only will sit in your local machine and will play role as compiler. Once you compile `.styl` files it will give you raw css as output you can put that on any server you want to.

Comment: I'm working with VS Code and have recently start using LESS. `--bg-color: #fff;` and `color: var(--bg-color);` are now replaced with `@bg-color: #fff` and `color: @bg-color;` respectively and it works almost great. Upon saving style.less it automatically creates style.css and uploads it. It would be great if would automatically compile and upload style.min.css, but for the time being I am satisfied with creating style.min.css  when development stage is over and I change source in <head>. When I worked with css only it automatically created min.css upon Ctrl+S. Thank you all